# Difference between drupal_write_record and db_insert

Tags: database

I want to know what is the difference between drupal_write_record and db_insert
example :
can i translate that `drupal_write_record('MyCustomTable', $Myrecord, $primary_key);` to an insert query ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drupal_write_record` doesn't know by itself whether to do the insert or the update, but this is determined by the existence (or not) of the 3rd parameter: `$primary_keys` which defaults to `array()` while `db_insert` is to insert new record to database.

according to [drupal_write_record API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) documentation

> **$primary_keys:** To indicate that this is a new record to be inserted, omit this argument. If this is an update, this argument specifies the primary keys' field names. If there is only 1 field in the key, you may pass in a string; if there are multiple fields in the key, pass in an array.

Also

> Do not use `drupal_write_record()` within `hook_update_N()` functions, since the database schema cannot be relied upon when a user is running a series of updates. Instead, use db_insert() or db_update() to save the record.

Comment: Thank you, but can i replace a drupal_write_record by an insert ?

Comment: Not entirely, but you could with a `db_merge` @Mitch